# ERROR 1064(42000):You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual use near 'mysql Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql -u root -p my_database < /tmp/backup.sql
```

this is the code i am trying to execute, however, everytime I enter this command, I face this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: That looks like the first line of output when you run the `status` command in the mysql client. I don't think you have a viable backup file. How did you create `backup.sql`?

Comment: You should use `mysqldump` to create mysql backup files. It puts information like this in comments.

Comment: @BillKarwin, i created the  backup file with the following command: ' mysqldump -u root -p my_database employees > /tmp/backup.sql'

Comment: Then you must have overwritten it subsequently. The line shown in the error message does not appear in mysqldump output.

Comment: @BillKarwin, should delete the backup file, and create the backup again with the command I posted above?

Comment: try it in 3 steps. first login: mysql -u root -p then change the Schema with USE my_database; and then SOURCE /tmp/backup.sql to see where is the error

Comment: First try creating a new backup file with a different name (don't delete your current backup.sql), just in case the current backup file contains something important.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at `backup.sql` using `less` or another text viewing command.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Copyright (' at line 1 "

this is the complete error that I get when I execute the command

Comment: That's the same as the original error, what's your point?

Comment: The first line of a file written by `mysqldump` should look something like `-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

Comment: What does `type mysqldump` show? Maybe you have it aliased to something else.

Comment: @analyticstag please do not cross post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325834/error-106442000you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntaxcheck-the-manual-use-near